# ARFF File Error

Tags: weka, arff

I'm trying to create an arff-file, and I thought I had done a pretty good job until I tried to open the file with WEKA: "nominal value not declared in header, read token[0], line 18". Here's my file:

```
    @relation 'wettermessung'
    @attribute Stations_ID numeric
    @attribute Datum date 'dd.MM.yyyy'
    @attribute Qualitaet numeric
    @attribute Min_5cm numeric
    @attribute Min_2m numeric
    @attribute Mittel_2m numeric
    @attribute Max_2m numeric
    @attribute Relative_Feuchte numeric
    @attribute Mittel_Windstaerke numeric
    @attribute Max_Windgeschwindigkeit numeric
    @attribute Sonnenscheindauer numeric
    @attribute Mittel_Bedeckungsgrad numeric
    @attribute Niederschlagshoehe numeric
    @attribute Mittel_Luftdruck numeric
    @attribute kiteflying {yes, no}
    @data
    10004,15.01.2014,3,0,4,8,5,9,7,88,4,5,17,6,0,9,0,0,1004,3,no
    10004,16.01.2014,3,0,5,7,6,9,7,7,96,3,5,14,9,0,0,0,996,7,no
    10004,17.01.2014,3,0,6,8,7,5,8,88,4,5,15,2,1,0,0,996,6,no
    10004,18.01.2014,3,0,6,3,7,2,7,6,90,5,5,15,1,0,7,0,0,1000,6,no
    10004,19.01.2014,3,0,3,7,5,3,6,8,89,7,7,24,4,0,0,0,1001,8,yes
    ....
```

I just can't figure out what's gone wrong here!

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

In arff the @attribute must have the values that you are trying to find in the data and this is for nominal @attributes only.

In this case, the instance you are trying to pass has some value which is not included in the @attribute header.

See instance 18 and see what is missing.

also, what is this **Datum date**